# Why is appending to a List in Scala returning other List type?

Tags: list, scala, collections, types

Since searching for :+ doesn't yield any results (thanks google!) I couldn't find any answer to my question:

Why is:

```
a :+ b
```

resulting in

```
List[Any]
```

if both 'a' and 'b' are of type

```
List[Int]
```

try it out yourself, following won't compile (Scala 2.11.6, Idea14):

```
object AAA extends App {
  val a: List[Int] = List[Int]()
  val b: List[Int] = List[Int]()

  val x: List[Int] = a :+ b
}
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:+` appends a single element to a `List`. So you are appending a `List[Int]` to a `List[Int]`, resulting in something like (if `a` and `b` are both set to `List(1, 2)`):

```
List(1, 2, List(1, 2))
```

Scala calculates the most common type between the element type (`Int`) and the thing you append (`List[Int]`), which is `Any`.

You probably wanted to concatenate two lists:

```
val x: List[Int] = a ++ b
```

Comment: I am really surprised scala lets me do it at all. I would expect it to be forbidden to append [Any] to a typed collection.

Comment: @pmkrefeld It doesn't let you, as you say, it wouldn't compile when `x` is expected to be `List[Int]`.

Comment: I meant that I was surprised that a: List[Int] :+ b: Any is allowed at all, what is the use case supposed to be?

Comment: If you enable the scala compiler flag `-Xlint` you will get a warning when you infer an `any` type.  If you also add `-Xfatal-warnings` you'll turn that warning into an error.